# Handling/Merging Duplicate Objects/Primary Keys from API Response with Spring Data JPA

Tags: database, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm writing an app that calls an API to retrieve the game schedule for an MLB team, and then stores those games in an H2 database. Here's a sample API response:

```
{
    "gameEntries": [
        {
            "id": "51271",
            "date": "2019-03-28",
            "time": "2:10PM",
            "location": "Miller Park",
            "homeTeam": {
                "ID": "134",
                "Name": "Brewers"
            },
            "awayTeam": {
                "ID": "133",
                "Name": "Cardinals"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "51258",
            "date": "2019-03-29",
            "time": "8:10PM",
            "location": "Miller Park",
            "homeTeam": {
                "ID": "134",
                "Name": "Brewers"
            },
            "awayTeam": {
                "ID": "133",
                "Name": "Cardinals"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using `RestTemplate` to parse the response into my `Schedule` object. Here is my data model:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Schedule {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("gameEntries")
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Game> games;
}
```

```java
@Data
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Game {
    @Id
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("date")
    private String date;

    @JsonProperty("time")
    private String time;

    @JsonProperty("location")
    private String location;

    @JsonProperty("homeTeam")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Team homeTeam;

    @JsonProperty("awayTeam")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Team awayTeam;
}
```

```java
@Data
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Team {
    @Id
    @JsonProperty("ID")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;
}
```

When I retrieve the schedule, I write it to the DB (using a JpaRepository) with the `saveAndFlush()` method. This is the error I get:

```sh
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.chrisjansson.mlbcalendar.model.Team#134]; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.chrisjansson.mlbcalendar.model.Team#134]
```

I know the error happens because when Spring tries to write the second `Game` to the database, there are already existing rows in my `Team` table for those two teams. Since the `id` field is the primary key for the `Team` entity, it sees a duplicate primary key value and fails to persist the second `Game`.

That being said, I'm not sure what to change in order to make this work. I tried setting `CascadeType.MERGE` on the `Team` fields, but that resulted in other issues.